# Get TRUE for each row whenever any of specific column values exist in an external vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column on a dataframe, where TRUE or 'Yes' is specified if any of the values of a row across specific columns exist in an external vector.

```r
vector<-c('a', 'f', 'm')

df

COL1    SR3   SR_op   letter  SR_2
12       y     f       ab      m
76       e     r       cd      t
90       a     b       jk      c 
40       z     f       fg      4
34       u     v       xy      w
```

I was trying this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(.cols= starts_with('SR'), ~ case_when(. %in% vector ~ 'Yes')))
```

I would like to get the following:

```r
COL1    SR3   SR_op   letter  SR_2  in_vector
12       y     f       ab      m      Yes
76       e     r       cd      t      NA
90       a     b       jk      c      Yes
40       z     f       fg      4      Yes
34       u     v       xy      w      NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `if_any`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  mutate(in_vector = if_any(starts_with('SR'), ~ .x %in% vector))

#   COL1 SR3 SR_op letter SR_2 in_vector
# 1   12   y     f     ab    m      TRUE
# 2   76   e     r     cd    t     FALSE
# 3   90   a     b     jk    c      TRUE
# 4   40   z     f     fg    4      TRUE
# 5   34   u     v     xy    w     FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `pick` out the columns you want to see if `any` values in the picked columns match `my_vector`, in a row-wise fashion.

```r
library(dplyr)

my_vector <- c("a", "f", "m")

df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(in_vector = any(pick(starts_with("SR")) %in% my_vector)) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 × 6
   COL1 SR3   SR_op letter SR_2  in_vector
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <lgl>    
1    12 y     f     ab     m     TRUE     
2    76 e     r     cd     t     FALSE    
3    90 a     b     jk     c     TRUE     
4    40 z     f     fg     4     TRUE     
5    34 u     v     xy     w     FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```r
df$bool <- apply(df[, -1L], 1L, \(x) any(x %in% vector))
df
#>   COL1 SR3 SR_op letter SR_2  bool
#> 1   12   y     f     ab    m  TRUE
#> 2   76   e     r     cd    t FALSE
#> 3   90   a     b     jk    c  TRUE
#> 4   40   z     f     fg    4  TRUE
#> 5   34   u     v     xy    w FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

No need for any additional packages. Just familiarise yourself with the `*apply()`-family, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family). If the operation should be done on column names including `SR` only, then replace `-1L` in `df[, 1L]` with `grep(pattern = "SR", x = colnames(df))`, i.e., `df[, grep(pattern = "SR", x = colnames(df))]` .

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "COL1    SR3   SR_op   letter  SR_2
12       y     f       ab      m
76       e     r       cd      t
90       a     b       jk      c 
40       z     f       fg      4
34       u     v       xy      w", header = TRUE)

vector <-c('a', 'f', 'm')
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively please try the below code

```r
df$in_vector <- sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) ifelse(any(unlist(vector) %in% unlist(df[x,c('SR3','SR_op','SR_2')])), 'Y', 'N'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  COL1 SR3 SR_op letter SR_2 in_vector
1   12   y     f     ab    m         Y
2   76   e     r     cd    t         N
3   90   a     b     jk    c         Y
4   40   z     f     fg    4         Y
5   34   u     v     xy    w         N
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `matrix` + `%in%` + `rowSums`

```
df$in_vector <- rowSums(matrix(as.matrix(df) %in% vector, nrow(df))) > 0
```

which should give

```
  COL1 SR3 SR_op letter SR_2 in_vector
1   12   y     f     ab    m      TRUE
2   76   e     r     cd    t     FALSE
3   90   a     b     jk    c      TRUE
4   40   z     f     fg    4      TRUE
5   34   u     v     xy    w     FALSE
```